# Wildcard SSL certificates on Cloud66

Tags: ssl, ssl-certificate, cloud66

We currently have a single development environment with [Cloud66](http://www.cloud66.com). We are hoping to expand to staging and production environments which will be secured with SSL.

Is it possible to use the same wildcard certificate to secure all three environments (obviously with different names for each)?

I've added the detail below as I don't think my original question was clear enough.

Specifically what I want to know is if Cloud66 will allow a single wildcard certificate to be used to secure domains across a number of stacks or if a single certificate can only be used on a single stack.

Comment: Yes it is possible... your question is closed ended; are you looking for more than yes/no?

Comment: A yes/no would be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  When you order a wildcard SSL certificate you can use it to secure multiple sites assuming they each use the same base domain of the wildcard certificate.

Comment: Can you confirm that would also work with Cloud66? I realise it ought to but just in case they have something quirky about their setup.

Comment: In this blog article they mention using wildcard certificates, so I I'm pretty sure.  You can test by generating your own self signed wildcard certificate before paying the money for a real one.

Comment: I know they support wildcard certificates, but what I don't know is if a single wildcard certficate can be used on Cloud66 to support domains across a number of separate stacks.

Comment: Yes; the same wildcard certificate can be installed on multiple stacks (IIS, nodejs, nginx, etc.) and be used to serve different subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, **Wildcard SSL certificate** is used to secure multiple domain names but your main domain name will be same.

Using wildcard you can secure
 
www.yourdomain.com
blog.yourdomain.com
login.yourdomain.com
secure.yourdomain.com
etc.yourdomain.com.